# What's the difference between these two writing style of Perl if, why are the result different?

Tags: perl, if-statement

I have write these two, but they got different result. I am not sure where is wrong.

For the first style, I put the operation before " if " condition:

```
$da{$array[0]}++ and $str="\n$array[0]\t$array[1]\t$array[-2]\n" if(exists $da{$array[0]} and $str!~/$array[0]\t$array[1]\t$array[-2]/);
```

and the result is: 
R8112033    3 
R8112038    1 
R8112056    1 
R8112057    1

while for the second common style:

```
if(exists $da{$array[0]} and $str!~/$array[0]\t$array[1]\t$array[-2]/)
  {
    $da{$array[0]}++;
    $str="\n$array[0]\t$array[1]\t$array[-2]\n";
  }
```

the result is: 
R8112033    2 
R8112038    1 
R8112056    1 
R8112057    1

The second result is what I want, but I don't know why it won't work in the first style.

Here is the data file: 
R8112033    EGFR    T790M   missense_mutation   No 
R8112033    EGFR    L858R   missense_mutation   No 
R8112033    TP53    -   missense_mutation   No 
R8112038    KRAS    G12D    missense_mutation   No 
R8112056    -   L858R   missense_mutation   Yes 
R8112057    KRAS    G12C    missense_mutation   No

Here is the full code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile=shift;
my %da;
my $str=0;
open IN, "$infile" or die $!;
while(<IN>)
{
        s/\r|\n//g;
        my @array = split /\t/,$_;
        $da{$array[0]}=0 if($array[-3]=~/\w/);
}
close IN;

open IN, "$infile" or die $!;
while(<IN>)
{
        s/\r|\n//g;
        my @array = split /\t/,$_;
        $da{$array[0]}++ and $str="\n$array[0]\t$array[1]\t$array[-2]\n" if(exists $da{$array[0]} and $str!~/$array[0]\t$array[1]\t$array[-2]/);
        #if(exists $da{$array[0]} and $str!~/$array[0]\t$array[1]\t$array[-2]/)
        #{
        #        $da{$array[0]}++;
        #        $str="\n$array[0]\t$array[1]\t$array[-2]\n";
        #}
}
close IN;

for my $key (sort keys %da)
{
        print "$key\t$da{$key}\n";
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get different results because

```perl
$da{$array[0]}++ and $str = "..."
```

and

```perl
$da{$array[0]}++;  $str = "..."
```

are not equivalent. The second evaluates both expressions, while the first might not execute the assignment.

Comment: +1. Specifically, the first one won't execute the assignment if `$da{$array[0]}` was zero or undefined before the increment.

Comment: @ikegami@ruakh, thank you for your answer.  Yes, if `$da{$array[0]}` was zero, the `$str=...` won't be executed.